# sql server bcp xml data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, bcp

I have a table which has a column which is of type xml.
I have to extract data from this table and load the data into another environment.
i am using bcp to extract and laod the target table but there are some special characters that is causing some issues when i bcp them into the target table. are there any workarounds

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 3):

A custom CLR-SP provided me with the best solution.  Now I can write XML-typed data directly to a file from TSQL, provided the SQL service account has permission to the file.  This allows the simple syntax:

```
exec dbo.clr_xml2file @xml, @path, @bool_overwrite
```

The SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[clr_xml2file]
    @xml [xml],
    @file [nvarchar](max),
    @overwrite [bit]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [CLR_FileIO].[FreddyB.FileIO].[Xml2File]
```

The C# for the CLR DLL:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace FreddyB
{  
  public class FileIO
  {
    public static void Xml2File(
      SqlXml xml, 
      SqlString sFile, 
      SqlBoolean bOverwrite
    ) {

      SqlPipe sqlpipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
      try
      {
        if (xml == null || xml.IsNull || xml.Value.Length == 0) {
          sqlpipe.Send("Cannot write empty content to file : \n\t"
            +sFile.Value);
          return;
        }

        if (File.Exists(sFile.Value) & bOverwrite.IsFalse) {
          sqlpipe.Send("File already exists : \n\t"+sFile.Value);
          return;
        }

        int iFileSize = 0;
        FileStream fs = null;
        try {
          byte[] ba = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.Value);
          iFileSize = ba.Length;

          fs = new FileStream(sFile.Value, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
          fs.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

          sqlpipe.Send("Wrote "
            +String.Format("{0:0,0.0}",iFileSize/1024)
            +" KB to : \n\t"
            +sFile.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
          sqlpipe.Send("Error as '"
            +WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
            +"' during file write : \n\t"
            +ex.Message);
          sqlpipe.Send("Stack trace : \n"+ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
          if (fs != null) {
            fs.Close();
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        sqlpipe.Send("Error writing to file : \n\t"
          +ex.Message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```